# How To Show MessageBox if Quantity Textbox Value Greater Then Available Stock In Database

Tags: c#

I am using c# Windows Form.

I have a quantity textbox if i type more then available stock for an selected item so how can i show messagebox and i want textbox.maxlength should be equal to available stock.

Thanks

My Available stock is 16 and i can type 20 in my quantity textbox i want to show error if quantity textBox value more than available stock.
[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOPil.png)

`if (txt_qty.Text > lbl_Stock.Text)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Your Available Stock Is Less");
            }`

Comment: This sentence doesn't make sense. Consider rewriting.

Comment: Check the image now i updated my question hope you will understand

Comment: What have to written so far? Post your code.

Comment: `if (txt_qty.Text > lbl_Stock.Text)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Your Available Stock Is Less");
            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the very little information you have given, it sounds like you just need some logic?

On text change event for txt_qty, you need something like this.

```
if (Convert.ToInt(txt_qty.Text) > Convert.ToInt(lbl_Stock.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Your Available Stock Is Less");
    txt_qty.Text = lbl_Stock.Text;
}
```

However, it would seem you also mentioned a `maxlength` of the textbox. This is the max length of the string the text box can hold, not the max length of an integer, as I suspect you want.

Hint:

Textboxes only hold strings. You need to convert its contents to an integer for a comparison.

Comment: Yes its works now i just want simple logic and i want to set my quantity textbox length equal to available stock?

Comment: Just set the textbox.text to the value of the label.text after the messagebox. updated my answer.

Comment: Thank You ;) Now Everything working perfectly.